# Why this strange symbol in hidden element

Tags: php, security, forms

I've seen a form that has the following hidden elements. The first one is obviously a security token for CSRF, but what's the second one. It's more or less an image. What added security would it give me? and how do I generate one?

```
<input type="hidden" value="G2k2DNFer3z2NR0zYO" name="key">
<input type="hidden" value="☃" name="_face">
<input type="hidden" value="home" name="ref_source">
```

Comment: Strange that it's called `_face`, because [it's actually a snowman](http://unicodesnowmanforyou.com).

Comment: @BoltClock Cool, he even has his own website!

Comment: @BoltClock The snowman symbol is actually one of [many characters in the "Miscellaneous Symbols" block](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf) as defined by the Unicode standard. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That SNOWMAN is actually a character in Unicode (U+2603) and it is probably used to test whether the client uses a proper character encoding (probably UTF-8) or not, for example:

```
$isUtf8 = $_POST['_face'] === "\xE2\x98\x83";
```

Comment: I see. So is this something we should all be doing in our forms? I'm asking because the website would get this information only after the user submits the form, so when the page is being rendered for the first time, this information is unavailable. Why might the website need it after that?

Comment: @samquo: There are some that suggest doing this to tell UTF-8 from other character encodings apart (see for example [“Unicode and Other Funny Characters” on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/unicode.html)). But I’m not sure if that’s really necessary. Because in general, the client uses either the character encoding specified in the [`accept-charset` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset) or the same character encoding that the form document was served with.

Comment: @samquo: But if you want to use such, choose characters that are also present in the default/fall-back character sets like the ones mentioned in the article (i.e. `ä™®`). Because the *SNOWMAN* is neither in Windows-1252 nor in ISO 8859-1 and I’m not sure how these mentioned buggy browsers would handle that character.